# How to hook up service activator to sftp:inbound-channel-adapter

Tags: spring-integration, sftp

Case : I want to get a file from SMTP server to local and I want to do post processing once the file is downloaded to local. 
I want to do a business logic (like uploading to aws s3 )after downloading every file. Whenever a file is downloaded to local I want to call `messageHandler.handleSftp()`. Any advice?

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter"
    auto-startup="true" channel="receiveChannel"

    session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
    local-directory="file:/fluentbatch/sftp" remote-directory="/tmp/datlaa"
    auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="false"
    filename-pattern="*.txt">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="receiveChannel">
</int:channel>

<int:service-activator input-channel="receiveChannel"
    method="handleSftp" ref="messageHandler" output-channel="nullChannel" auto-startup="true">
</int:service-activator>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking; `MessageHandler.handleSftp(File foo)` is just a POJO method that gets the `File` payload.

Comment: Gary i want to invoke service activator to do some business logic when ever i get a new file. how to configure it.?

Comment: What you have will do that.

Comment: Thanks Gary its working fine.If i remove the file from my local , and the same file is there in server  its coping to local but not calling the service-activator

Comment: See [the documentation about local-filter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-inbound); by default, the local filter will only allow a file to be processed once. If you wish to process the same filename, change it to an `AcceptAllFileListFilter`.